# Restart a dataGridView to its empty state

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView that its being filled automatically from a SQL Table, the dataGridView is used for seeing all the general data from any table that is selected from a comboBox.

Lets suppose that the tables have the following "columns":

Table A has 1, 2 and 3
Table B has only 4 and 5

When I select the first table there is no problem (shows 1, 2 and 3), but when I change, the columns from the last selected table are still showing (shows 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5), they do not have any data but the columns still there.

How can I reset the datagridview to an empty state so when I change the table only columns from that table are shown.

I have already tried these 3 options:

```
dataTable.Clear();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

dataTable=null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this after any option of the three

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

for example:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```